# How do i convert list into python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have used for loop for text extraction from images. So i getting errors while converting list into python pandas dataframe.

```
info = []
for item in dirs:
    if os.path.isfile(path+item):
        for a in x:
            img = Image.open(path+item)
            crop = img.crop(a)
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(crop)
            info.append(text)
df = pd.DataFrame([info], colnames=['col1','col2'])
df
```

Expected result: data store in dataframe row wise.

Yes list is not a list of two items. i have 14 predefined columns.
Here it is another code
    for i in range(info):
        df.loc[i] = [ info for n in range(14))

Comment: sharing the mistake would be useful (update question please)

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':info,'col2':info})`

Comment: Not working @il

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here I think.

First of all, you are passing to the DataFrame `[info]` although `info` is already a list. You can just pass this list as it is.

Now that you pass a list of items as argument, you're trying to convert the list as a DataFrame with two columns: `colnames=['col1','col2']`. And the keyword is `columns` not `colnames`.

I think that's the problem. You list is not a list of two-items list (like `[[a, b], [c, d]]`). Just use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(info, columns=['col1'])
```

Best

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(info) are used when you dont have pre-defined columns. So this one is i think not going to work.

Comment: Yes list is not a list of two iteams.

Answer (score 1):

Please check documentation for .DataFrame
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

The line in which you create your dataframe

> df = pd.DataFrame([info], colnames=['col1','col2']

Is missing parenthesis at the end, uses colnames instead of columns, has unnecessary square brackets around your list and is creating two columns where you only need one.

Please mention the exact error